# 7- Disable a block or edit it without access to the admin interface

Tags: 7

I activated php code in a block in the header, and I put "echo $user;" instead of "echo $user->name;".

Now I get an error on page load and can't edit the block to correct the mistake.

If I could change the active admin theme back to bartik, that would also solve the problem.

Any ideas welcome. Thanks

Edit: ok I think I solved by deleting my custom theme folder. Good that the block was only enabled for the custom theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have devel installed, you can edit the default theme by editing theme_default variable.
http://yoursite.com/devel/variable/edit/theme_default

Or deactivate the block in your database

update blocks set status = 0 where delta = 'block';